# GA4 : Custom Dimension displays the value in exponential form

Tags: migration, google-analytics-4, custom-dimensions

I am currently working on GA4 migration. We have a custom dimension that receives value in number format with 37 digits. But the value of the custom dimension is populated in the exponential format in real time report, custom report and the application that receives the data.

```
Actual dimension value: 86594184624443841463509305394505323179

GA4 Custom Dimension value : 8.65941846244438E+37
```

With UA, we are not facing this issue. The value is received as it is. Kindly help us to understand why the value is converted in GA4. Please provide any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Thank you!!

Comment: Looks like another bug of GA4. Unless you're actively doing math on that dimension in GA4, consider switching it from numeric to string. This should fix the issue.

Comment: @BNazaruk,  Thank you for the reply! May I ask how to define the custom dimension data type as string. We retrieve this value using a JavaScript function that return var. Is it possible to define the custom dimension datatype to be string anywhere in the GA4 property.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a CD and not a CM? Cuz you can select a type for CM, but not for CDs. CDs are implied to be strings. If you see your CD being reported in the exponential format, it likely means it's another bug in GA4's UI. You should still be able to see the real number when you export the data. Another fix for that bug would be changing the format of the data in that dimension so that it wouldn't be interpreted as an int or moving it to a CM. But it's a poor solution since it doesn't fix the historical data.

Comment: Hi, yes, we are using CD as this is a parameter that captures a value from the page URL. We did try to change the format of the data in the dimension to string. Still the GA4 is returning value in exponential form even though the value returned is a string. Checking whether this dimension can be captured as a metric but this is a value captured for every page refresh and I think cannot be considered as a metric.

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of how that dimension looks like from the Network tab? Or via the Adswerve's DL debugger extension. I'm looking for the ep/epn key with your number in that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's GA4 bug. Try adding a dot (or other symbol, not a number) at the end of your value (example: 86594184624443841463509305394505323179.) I send to GA4 Client ID (string) as CD and GA4 transforms it to the number. So I have to add a dot at the end and then delete it in the exported reports.